# counting T/F values for several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, count

I am a beginner using pandas.

I'm looking for mutations on several patients. I have 16 different conditions. I simply write a code about it but how can do this by for loop? I try to find the changes on MUT column and set them as True and False. Then try to count the True/False numbers. I have done for only 4.

Can you suggest a more simple way, instead of writing the same code 16 times?

```
s1=df["MUT"]
A_T= s1.str.contains("A:T")
ATnum= A_T.value_counts(sort=True)

s2=df["MUT"]
A_G=s2.str.contains("A:G")
AGnum=A_G.value_counts(sort=True)

s3=df["MUT"]
A_C=s3.str.contains("A:C")
ACnum=A_C.value_counts(sort=True)

s4=df["MUT"]
A__=s4.str.contains("A:-")
A_num=A__.value_counts(sort=True)
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just do `df["MUT"].value_counts()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert with using Pandas, so don't know if there's a cleaner way of doing this, but perhaps the following might work?

```
chars = 'TGC-'
nums = {}

for char in chars:
    s = df["MUT"]
    A = s.str.contains("A:" + char)
    num = A.value_counts(sort=True)
    nums[char] = num

ATnum = nums['T']
AGnum = nums['G']
# ...etc
```

Basically, go through each unique character (T, G, C, -) then pull out the values that you need, then finally stick the numbers in a dictionary. Then, once the loop is finished, you can fetch whatever numbers you need back out of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts), this will give you a count of all unique values in your column, no need to create 16 variables:

```
In [5]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'MUT':np.random.randint(0,16,100)})
df['MUT'].value_counts()

Out[5]:
6     11
14    10
13     9
12     9
1      8
9      7
15     6
11     6
8      5
5      5
3      5
2      5
10     4
4      4
7      3
0      3
dtype: int64
```